# PHP SimpleXML: handling XSD schema tags

Tags: php, xsd, simplexml

I use `foreach($node->children() as $childNode)` to loop all childs for node. It works fine when child nodes is like `<nodename>content</nodename>`.

When node is like:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
targetNamespace="https://www.w3schools.com"
xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com"
elementFormDefault="qualified">
</xs:schema>
```

it doesn't work. This nodes as if ignored in foreach.

My file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root attr1="asasasa" attr2="dscd">
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
targetNamespace="https://www.w3schools.com"
xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com"
elementFormDefault="qualified">
</xs:schema>
  <Params>
    <node>content</node>
    <newnode>content 2</newnode>
  </Params>
</root>
```

Code:

```
$node = simplexml_load_file($path, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);

foreach($node->children() as $childNode) { ... }
```

On the first iteration of loop - $childNode is , but I need first

How to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you share your code you tried, XML and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two namespaces in the document. So I'm assuming you have to do it twice:

```
foreach($node->children("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema") as $childNode) {
    var_dump($childNode);
}
foreach($node->children() as $childNode) {
    var_dump($childNode);
}
```

or you could use `xpath`:

```
foreach ($node->xpath ("/root/*") as $n)
{
    var_dump ($n);
}
```

or with all the attributes:

```
foreach ($node->xpath ("./*") as $n)
{
    var_dump ($n);
    var_dump ($n->getNamespaces());
}
```

Comment: Maybe is there are ways to loop all nodes (with different namespaces) in the same order?

Comment: Thank you, I changed the xpath query a little `bit - $node->xpath('./*')`. Now I can access all childs.

Comment: Now how to do the same with attributes? For example, how to get ALL attributes for current node including attributes with namespace?

Comment: Use "./node()" instead then.

Comment: It's strange, works for me. Use `$n->getNamespaces()` and `$n->attributes()` then.

Comment: Still can't get in attributes list `xmlns:xs` and `xmlns` :(

Comment: `xmlns:xs` is called simply `xs` and is avaiable through `$n->attributes()`. `xmlns` is the default namespace and is available through `$node->getDocNamespaces(true)`